# Facebook like generated button saying share instead

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing an app and I noticed that on Chrome, their like button code generates a button that says share. If I choose the other option (recommend) it does indeed say recommend. On Firefox oddly it still says like and recommend. Personally, I'd like it to say like which is why I'm posting. Is there perhaps there is an undocumented change/method to get it to say like now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make it say "like" instead of "share"? If so, you just need to find and replace the word "share" with the word "like".

Comment: Yes, the generated button says share on Chrome, but like on Firefox. There isn't anything to search and replace on. According to the generated code, it should say like, but it doesn't (on Chrome).